# Yi2 Download File Using SendFile()

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii2

I am attempting to use the built in function sendFile() provided by Yii2 to allow users to download files. This will not, however, actually download the file.

Below is my ajax code

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'https://'+window.location.hostname+'/download',
     dataType: "json",
     type: 'POST',
     data: {name: name},
   })
```

Server side code

```
  $filename = "test.txt";
  $path = Yii::getAlias('@webroot')."/uploads/test.txt";
  Yii::$app->response->sendFile($path, $filename)->send();



  //I've also tried variations of the file path and name. E.G:
  $filename = "test.txt";
  $path = Yii::getAlias('@webroot')."/uploads";
```

The code provided above is what I am currently using to download the file. When a user clicks on a download icon, an Ajax call is made to the action containing the logic above, thus sending that file to the user's browser.

When the Ajax call is made, the server returns `200` but doesn't actually download the file. Instead, in the response is the content of the file being requested. For instance, if the user requests a file containing the text `'Hello there!'`, when the Ajax call is finished, nothing will be downloaded but the server response (as seen through FireFox dev tools) shows `'Hello there!'`.

Is there any reason why the file itself isn't downloading?

If I just navigate to the url (lets say its `localhost/downloadFile`) in another tab, the action is called, the download dialogue opens, and I can download the file.

Comment: you need to **`return`** the statement if i am not wrong. and why are you calling `->send()` just use like `return Yii::$app->response->sendFile($path, $filename)`

Comment: and add your javascript code where you are sending the ajax request

Comment: I've updated the code to include the Ajax call as well as the return statement adjustments that you suggested. Even with these changes, I get the same result.

Comment: You should not change the original code in the question as it misleads the answer, and keep it the same as you have it originally in your working code before i suggested you things above. moreover see the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First thing you have to `return` the statement, and there isnt any use of calling `send()` after the `sendFile()` if you are returning it from the controller action, just keep it like below

   ```
    return Yii::$app->response->sendFile($path, $filename);
   ```
2. Ajax isnt for file downloads you should either create a popup window or simply use

   ```
    window.location.assign('https://'+window.location.hostname+'/download/'+name);
   ```

And you will see that the page wont change that you are currently on and the file download dialog will be triggered.

Comment: Thank you! You're right, Ajax was the main issue here. The suggestions provided above worked.